# Setting first section of a page as the section in heading

Tags: fancyhdr

I'm using the fancyhdr package for my heading, and I want the section name in the heading to show the first section that appears in the current page.
For example, if I have three sections in one page like this:

Beginning

Middle

End

I want my heading to to say "Beginning" and not "End". Currently, my heading displays the last one.

Here is my heading code:

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead[R]{\today}
\fancyhead[L]{\leftmark}
\setlength{\headheight}{20pt}
\setlength{\headsep}{0.2in}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could define and use `\leftfirstmark`:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\leftfirstmark}{%
  \expandafter\@leftmark\firstmark\@empty\@empty
}
\makeatother
```

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}% only for dummy text

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\leftfirstmark}{%
  \expandafter\@leftmark\firstmark\@empty\@empty
}
\makeatother

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead[R]{\today}
\fancyhead[L]{\leftfirstmark}
\setlength{\headheight}{20pt}
\setlength{\headsep}{0.2in}


\begin{document}
\section{Beginning}
\lipsum[1]
\section{Middle}
\lipsum[2]
\section{End}
\lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```

[image]